# Get the array value using array index inside the nested arrays in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
MongoDb Tree Mode,

    StaffId                         555                 
    StaffName                       Bell
    Course                          [2 Elements]
        [0]                         [1 Fields]
            CourseInformation       [2 Elements]
                [0]                 [3 Fields]
                    StudentName     Brett Lee
                    CourseCode      MS
                    CourseDuration  24
                [1]                 [3 Fields]
                    StudentName     Lebron
                    CourseCode      ME
                    CourseDuration  24
        [1]                         [1 Fields]
            CourseInformation       [2 Elements]
                [0]                 [3 Fields]
                    StudentName     Roman
                    CourseCode      MSC
                    CourseDuration  12
                [1]                 [3 Fields]
                    StudentName     Neymar
                    CourseCode      MT
                    CourseDuration  12
```

Query Used:

```
db.col.find({StaffId:'555'}, { 
    CourseInformation   : {
        $elemMatch: {
        StudentName : {$ne:null},
        CourseCode  : {$ne:null},
        CourseDuration  : {$ne:null},
        }
    }
})
```

**Actual Output**

> _id (Objectid(XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)

**Expected Output**

> Brett Lee MS 24 Lebron ME 24 Roman MSC 12 Neymar MT 12

Assistance/Guidance Required:
How can we get the values or how can we traverse inside nested arrays and return only the values ?

Any leads would be greatly appreciated!!!

End Goal: I've to store these values and compare with the string

Comment: Please provide 3 sample documents and the expected output for them, and we'll show you how to get there.

Comment: @nimrodserok - Thank You, Please find the details updated.

Comment: There are no sample documents here...